# How to populate a 2 dimension array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have N numbers, N=10, how to populate it into a 2-D array so it looks like this:

```
{{1 2 3 4 5 }
 {6 7 8 9 10}}
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
int[][] a = new int[2][5]
for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
  for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
    a[i][j] = ?
 }
}
```

Or this is not possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the number in a variable, and increase it after each iteration:

```
int i = 1;

for (...) {
    for (...) {
        a[i][j] = i++; // the ++ operator will increase it by one
    }
}
```

Comment: You will have to work harder and practice, practice, practice! It's not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

Given your first array, `a` I think you want something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[][] a = new int[2][5];
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
      a[i][j] = j + (a[i].length * i) + 1;
    }
  }
  System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a));
}
```

Output is

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Comment: This seems more generic. But why does it work so nicely?

Answer (score 0):

### Either you can increment `var` and fill the array:

```
int var = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) 
    {
        a[i][j] = var++; 
    }
}
```

### Or you can use `Scanner` and take in some input from the user:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) 
    {
        a[i][j] = in.nextInt(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[][] a = new int[2][5];
int x = 1;
for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
  for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
      a[i][j] = x++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if the values are known at compile time or if you need something dynamic at runtime.  The sample in the original question and the answers above seem to suggest that maybe you are just trying to initialize the array with values known at compile time and if that is the case, you can do something like this:

```
int[][] nums = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}};
```